# What would be the best alternative to assigning a variable to null?

Tags: java, null, refactoring

When I code, I often assign my variables to null so I can use this information later on. Assigning my variables to null allow me to specify that the state of the variable is being invalid and doing so allow me to check the validity of the said variable later on in the program.

However, my code static analysis tools, such as PMD, yell when I assign a variable to null, stating that this is a code smell and I should consider refactoring.

So my question is the following : what would be the best alternative to assigning a variable to null when you want to specify that this variable as an invalid state ?

Comment: suppress PMD... it can't tell you what to do!

Comment: check this: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html or it's java8 analog http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: @ProPhil Can you show a code snippet where PMD complains? Context is important here.

Comment: don't invent a workaround just to satisfy a bureaucratic rule, it make things worse. remove or revise the rule instead.

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=59 @ProPhil check out my answer for more info...

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my favorite approaches is the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).  This is an object (not null) of the correct type - frequently a subclass of the type in question - which behaves correctly for null.  That is, if you call a method on it, nothing happens, but unlike a true null it doesn't cause an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **Optional** framework introduced in Java 8.

```
Optional<String> str = foo() // Method that returns an optional String
if(!str.isPresent()){
    // Invalid state
}else{
    String validStr = str.get();
    // Valid state
}
```

You initialise an optional with **Optional.of("")**

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to `null` is `empty` state.  For example `String` object can be `empty` it even has a method to check if it is empty `String.isEmpty()`.  Depending on your object you could have a method that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the `objects` state is empty or not empty.  This allows you to not use `nulls`. You can initialize your `object` to an `empty` state.  Just google null vs. empty and you will find a lot of information out there.  `Collections` are another example that can return `empty` objects (lists, sets, or maps in this case):

```
Collections.emptyList()
Collections.emptySet()
Collections.emptyMap()
```

[Java Prefer Empty to Null Link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=59)

[Avoid Nulls Link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=134)

All that being said there are still cases where `null` is useful.  A lot of it depends on your programming style and the specific case. `null` can be helpful for testing because your application will crash with `NPE` so you will be able to detect mistakes...where an `empty` object could cause a `logical` error which are sometimes harder to detect.  It is up to the programmer to decide what is best for each situation...

If you want to have an `empty` object with an `isEmpty()` method you just have to decide what "empty" means in your objects situation.  Then you can build your own rules around what constitutes your custom class `object` as being empty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with assigning null is that null can have several meaning: variable  (or field) is not initialized, value is absent, or inapplicable. So it is down to the programmer to remember  (or discover) what null means in a specific context.

Alternatives are to use the null object pattern or make use of option types (see Optional class in Java).
This wikipedia article covers it all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type

Now going back to PMD, I think it is up to your team to figure out if you want to follow this rule and how you want to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of variable. Usually null is the universal option for all variables. However the best option I have seen used is assigning the var to something that would rarely/very-unlikely ever be used.

For example:

String str = "I AM NULL";

Int num = MIN_INT;(I forgot the actual method call to MIN_INT, but the idea is the same).

Then you would check for those values in each case.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to assign the variable a value that you know you'll never ever use.

e.g. I used to give value to a string: "DELETED", which I know will never appear otherwise. This way it can not only deal with the PMD, but also avoid some potential NullPointerExceptions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using that variable for conditional purposes you should use Boolean.